# android LocationManager last position

Tags: java, android, eclipse, locationmanager

i have this code:

```
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.tempMap) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = null;
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)||locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 1, this);
        if (location != null) {
            Log.e("PROVIDER SCELTO", provider);
            onLocationChanged(location);
            Log.e("LATITUDE", String.valueOf(latitude));
            Log.e("LONGITUDE", String.valueOf(longitude));
```

and:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
}
```

but the last gps point that it return is the last point after i use the "google maps navigator". So, if i not use gm navigator, the latitude and longitude is not updated.

WHY???

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

location fix requires time wait till a good fix is recived this checks the time of the fix and sets location only if the fix is within a time period if you dont check the time of the fix it will provide the last fix recived irespective of when

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
Date dd=new Date(location.getTime());
    Date ddd=new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-(1000*60*15));
    Log.e("", String.valueOf(location.getTime()+":"+System.currentTimeMillis()+":"+dd+":"+ddd));
    if (dd.compareTo(ddd)==1?true:false) {
        got=true;
        latitude=String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        longitude=String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());}
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.
But if (dd.compareTo(ddd)==1?true:false) { it return false because dd is Sat Jul 13 20:58:50 and ddd is now.

Comment: check on a device ll never wrk n emulator